# how to load a char[] that's a member of Stuct[i]?

Tags: c, struct, char

Let's say we have this struct

```
struct Foo{
    int FooLength;       //length of Foo
    char FooChar[4];
};
```

and then in the main we have

```
int sizeFoo = 100; struct Foo myFooList[sizeFoo];
```

what would be the best way to input data for `FooChar`? Would `strncpy`, or `memcpy`, or `snprintf`, or `sprintf`?

what I wish to do is something like

```
myFooList[0].FooLength = 3;
myFooList[0].FooChar = "dog";
myFooList[1].FooLength = 3;
myFooList[1].FooChar = "cat";
.
.
.
```

with a correct syntax since in C you can't just = "string"; here, and I'm not sure what would be the best way to go about it?  I have look at similar topics, but I just get more confused with how `strncpy` or `sprintf` are not good or you have to have a `\0` added at the end or some other detail that makes picking what to do more difficult.

Also if all the values of `myFooList[]` are already know (they are const or static) is there a way to initialize like one would do any other array?

Comment: You cannot assign strings. You are attempting to assign the address of a *string literal*. `myFooList[0].FooChar = "dog";` should be `strcpy (myFooList[0].FooChar, "dog");` Always remember you must leave space for the *nul-terminating* character (you do here, but it's not clear whether that was purposeful)

Comment: `int sizeFoo = 100; struct Foo myFooList[sizeFoo];`, you are using a VLA of struct which cannot be initialized as part of the declaration. You will need to loop over your set of values and assign/strcpy.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Thanks for the tips, in my particular case doing assign with strcpy kind of like Nik said works for the most part. Wanted to made it seem more tidy up but it still end up with a loop approach.

Comment: Well, it is a little deeper than that. If you had declared `char *FooChar;` in your struct, you could assign `myFooList[0].FooChar = "dog";` because you are assigning the address of `"dog"`, a *sting literal*, to a *pointer*, which is fine. However, you have `char FooChar[4];` (an *array of type char*). To "*fill*" the array, you must copy data into it because you cannot assign a pointer (`char *`) to any element (`char`) of your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is always 3 characters, you can use `strcpy`, otherwise use `strncpy(myFooList[0].FooChar, "dog", 3)`. You must add the terminating null character if using `strncpy`. `strcpy` will add the termination null character automatically, just like VHS has in his answer. In either case, you should still validate that your input does not exceed the maximum length. To find the length of a string(i.e. the number of char characters up to the first null character), you would use `strlen`. To determine the capacity of a `char a[]`, you can use `_countof(a)`. Don't forget that one of those has to be a `'\0'`.

`memcpy` would also work, but it would be unusual to do that with a string.

You wouldn't use `sprintf` here. `sprintf` would normally be used when you need to create a unique string using dynamic data at runtime. This is not what you're doing here. If you have any experience with .NET, it is the C equivalent of `string.Format`.

To initialize an array of 'Foo', you will just need to write a function that will do that. Even if you figure out the syntax to do it in one line, it'll be very difficult to read and maintain. Here's an example without validation, I will leave that task to you.

```
myFooList[0].FooLength = 3;
strncpy(myFooList[0].FooChar, "dog", 3);
myFooList[0].FooChar[3] = '\0';

myFooList[1].FooLength = 3;
strncpy(myFooList[1].FooChar, "cat", 3);
myFooList[1].FooChar[3] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your integer assignment is correct, but the string assignment is not. Following is the right way:

```
myFooList[0].FooLength = 3;
strcpy( myFooList[0].FooChar, "dog");
myFooList[1].FooLength = 3;
strcpy(myFooList[1].FooChar, "cat");
```

Comment: thanks, that works? I thought strcpy can make some errors if it isn't terminated with `\0` ?

Comment: @FelipeSantana. The function `strcpy` will supply `\0` to the destination string after completing the copy. But you must make sure that the destination has enough space for the string being copied plus one more character (\0).

Comment: ah I thought one had to add the `\0` afterward, thanks for the clarification, so a right way would be to make sure the definition of `struct Foo`'s `FooChar[]` is big enough, and then use `strcpy` .

Answer (score 0):

> what would be the best way to input data for FooChar? Would strncpy,
>   or memcpy, or snprintf, or  sprintf? ...
>   but I just get more confused with how strncpy or sprintf are not good
>   or you have to have a \0 added at the end or some other detail that
>   makes picking what to do more difficult.

Well, memcpy is a good choice if you don't want terminate nul byte. I don't really understand what is your question here.

> Also if all the values of myFooList[] are already know (they are const
>   or static) is there a way to initialize like one would do any other
>   array?

In your example, no, because you use [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) who can't be initialize. But you could do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo {
  int FooLength; // length of Foo
  char FooChar[4];
};

int main(void) {
  struct Foo myFooList[] = {{3, "dog"}, {3, "cat"}};
  size_t size = sizeof myFooList / sizeof *myFooList;
}
```

Comment: and can   `struct Foo myFooList[] = {{3, "dog"}, {3, "cat"}};` actually be done if it isn't a VLA (Very Large Array?)?

Comment: The question was about strncpy, or memcpy, or snprintf, or sprintf doing all similar things but they seem to be better on some cases, and in some cases bad enough to send you to debug land for hours. also it there a time when is good to not terminate in a null?

Comment: @FelipeSantana If you want to have **valid** string in C, you **must** terminate them with `\0`. The answer to your question is very relative to the context. But if you begin in C, I advise you to always use simple function as strncpy() and always terminate your string with `\0`.